# Using Python to create a matrix whose rows have a correlation ≈ R∈[0,1]

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, simulation

I am trying to use Python to create a matrix whose values are pulled from a standard normal distribution and the rows are correlated with each other by a factor of about R∈[0,1]. The columns should be uncorrelated with each other. I would like to do so for N = 100,000 rows and M = 3000 columns.

For N around 3000 to 5000, the code runs rather quickly. However, as soon as N reaches around 10,000, the time it takes to create the effect_sizes matrix skyrockets (I checked each component of the code, and the creation of that specific matrix takes the overwhelming majority of the time). Is there any way I can optimize my code? I provide my current code below.

```
def draw_effects(N, M, R):
    '''
    creates a matrix that represents the effect sizes of M columns for N rows

    ARGS:
        N: the number of rows
        M: the number of columns
        R: the correlation of effect sizes across rows
    '''
    import numpy as np
    
    # Create a matrix representing the correlation across rows (1s along the diagonal, R everywhere else)

    cov = np.full((N, N), R)
    np.fill_diagonal(cov, 1)

    # Use multivariate normal to correlate rows of effect size matrix by R and draw each entry from a standard normal distribution.
    effect_sizes = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros(N), cov=cov, size=M).T
    
    return effect_sizes
```

I tried using np.random.multivariate_normal, a Cholesky decomposition, and some other methods. I was expecting other methods to decrease the amount of time needed to create the "effect_sizes" matrix, but I haven't gotten any breakthroughs yet.

Comment: You're working with a 74.5 GiB array. It takes a fair amount of time just to write to that much RAM, much less do math on it. The code you already have is probably close to optimal.

Comment: Very good observation @Brian61354270. I didn't even think about it in terms of memory. I now have a good idea of why it crashes on my local machine (32GB RAM), while it is extremely slow yet does not crash on my organization's remote server (much, much more RAM). Many thanks!